# ICS Integration on supplier Creation Business Object from EBS to ORACLE CLOUD facing the issue mention below

Tags: web-services, cloud, icalendar, soa, oracle-cloud-infrastructure-classic

I have made an integration in ICS on "supplier" creation and in the end point service on cloud side i have chosen 
Business Object: "supplier service" and operation :"creation" so when i am going to activate the integration it showing this error

Integration "EBS_SUPPLIER_CLOUD_INTG" cannot be activated because of an internal error. Incident has been created with ID: 385.CASDK-0005: A connector specific exception was raised by the application.{0}.Failed to located the service endpoint for the service {http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/prc/poz/suppliers/supplierServiceV2/}SupplierService. Please contact the administrator.

i have tested the supplier with a payload in soapUi .got success and supplier got created in cloud
Any One could Help with solution will be thankful.
Thanks!!!